# Query for getting distinct pairs from a single column with an added constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, select

How would I go about getting distinct pairs from a column with a constraint that a pair should not be repeated? So I have a query as such

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT s1.author_set_s_author_id,
         s2.author_set_s_author_id
FROM submission_record_author_set s1, submission_record_author_set s2
WHERE s1.author_set_s_author_id != s2.author_set_s_author_id;
```

This gets me all possible pairs from that column with a constraint that it cannot pair with it self but this can still happen:
(1,2) and (2,1).

A pair should never be repeated in my case. So the pair of 1 and 2 should only appear once. Any suggestions on how I would add that constraint to my SQL query?

Comment: if you do have (1,2) and (2,1) do you care which one you keep?

Comment: @P.Salmon nope, either one is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply replace the `!=` comparison in your `WHERE` clause with either `<` (to get `(1,2)` instead of `(2,1)`) or `>` (to get `(2,1)` instead of `(1,2)`):

```
SELECT DISTINCT s1.author_set_s_author_id,
                s2.author_set_s_author_id
FROM submission_record_author_set s1, submission_record_author_set s2
WHERE s1.author_set_s_author_id < s2.author_set_s_author_id;
```